# Query about using lorentz transforms to describe muon decay

Tags: special-relativity

[image]

Image from https://brilliant.org/practice/cosmic-ray-muons/?p=5.

On the above diagram, $T$ and $X$ correspond to the axis of an observer on Earth and $T'$ and $X'$ correspond to the axis of the moving muon. D is the distance from the atmosphere to the detector.

This probably won't require more than a comment but I really cant seem to understand why I get different muon decay times by the two following approaches:

Approach 1:

Muon measures proper time of decay ($\tau$) and so as the relation between measured time ($T_{Earth}$) and proper time is $\gamma \tau=T_{Earth}$. Using this equation gives me the correct time passed according to the muon for it to reach the detector.

Approach 2:

According to the lorentz transforms, the time a moving observer ascribes to an event is related to the time and position ascribed by a stationary observer by $T'=\gamma (T-\frac{vx}{c^2})$.

So I thought that this would mean $\tau =\gamma (T_{Earth}-\frac{v_{muon}D}{c^2})$.

The two don't seem to give me the same answer, why is that?

Comment: They do give the same answer, since we have $D=v_{\text{muon}} T_{\text{Earth}} $.

Comment: How, doesn't that mean $T_{Earth}-\frac{v_{muon}D}{c^2}$.=$\frac{T_{Earth}-\frac{v_{muon}D}{c^2}}{\gamma^2}$.

Comment: No, we have $T_{\text{Earth}}-\frac{v_{\text{muon}}D}{c^2}=\frac{T_{\text{Earth}}}{\gamma^2}=\frac{\tau}{\gamma}$, which, if you expand out the definitions, is in fact an identity